# How can I stop a Coroutine but let the alpha color to finish fading first before stopping?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two problems :

- I had to use a flag and a break; to stop the Coroutine CanvasAlphaChangeOverTime just doing :

  StopCoroutine("CanvasAlphaChangeOverTime"); Didn't stop it.
- How can I make that if the fading is moving to the 0 on the way to 0 or on the way to 1 and I stop the Coroutine CanvasAlphaChangeOverTime that first it will finish fading to the direction it is to 0 or to 1 and then stop the Coroutine ?

Now when the Coroutine stop it's stopping the fading in the middle and I want the fading to finish first then to stop.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FadeInOutSaveGameText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator animator;
    public Canvas canvas;
    public float fadingSpeed;

    private bool stopFading = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(OverAllTime(5f));
    }

    IEnumerator CanvasAlphaChangeOverTime(Canvas canvas, float duration)
    {
        var alphaColor = canvas.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha;

        while (true)
        {
            alphaColor = (Mathf.Sin(Time.time * duration) + 1.0f) / 2.0f;
            canvas.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = alphaColor;

            if (stopFading == true)
            {
                break;
            }

            yield return null;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator OverAllTime(float time)
    {
        StartCoroutine(CanvasAlphaChangeOverTime(canvas, fadingSpeed));

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

        stopFading = true;
        StopCoroutine("CanvasAlphaChangeOverTime");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are mixing how you start and try to stop the coroutine (IEnumerator vs String), which the documentation explicitly says not to do: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to stop your coroutine you have to store the return value of StartCoroutine(...) in a member variable and stop it explicitly by its reference:

```
private Coroutine coroutine;
[...]
private void StartRoutine 
{
    if(coroutine == null)
        coroutine = StartCoroutine(...);
}

private void StopRoutine 
{
    if(coroutine != null)
    {
        StopCoroutine(coroutine);
        coroutine = null;
    }
}
```

But in your case you do not want to stop the coroutine, since you want it to continue until reaching it's turning point (and then finish by itself).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FadeInOutSaveGameText : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const float THRESHOLD = 0.01F;

    [...]

    IEnumerator CanvasAlphaChangeOverTime(Canvas canvas, float duration)
    {
        var alphaColor = canvas.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha;

        while (true)
        {
            alphaColor = (Mathf.Sin(Time.time * duration) + 1.0f) / 2.0f;
            canvas.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = alphaColor;

            // only break, if current alpha value is close to 0
            if (stopFading && Mathf.Abs(alphaColor) <= THRESHOLD)
            {
                break;
            }

            yield return null;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator OverAllTime(float time)
    {
        StartCoroutine(CanvasAlphaChangeOverTime(canvas, fadingSpeed));

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

        stopFading = true;
        // do not stop routine, since it should run on until reaching 0
        //StopCoroutine("CanvasAlphaChangeOverTime");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working. I just have a question about extending it a bit. If the fading is ending with 1 for example when I set it to 5 seconds it's ending with 1 if I set the seconds to 3 it's ending with 0. Is there a way to force it to finish always at 0 ? I mean if I set it to 5 seconds it's fading in out and after 5 seconds it stop when the value is 1 then to extend the time for another fade so it will end at value 0.

Comment: So if the time was set to 5 seconds the overall time to 5 seconds and when it stop if it stop on value 1 then extend the time by another second or so and make it fade to 0 and then stop.  So no matter what time it will be 10 seconds or 30 seconds or 2 seconds it will end at value 0.

Comment: I'm using it to display a text ui showing "Saving Game" indicating message when the game is being saving.  The logic should be I think that the fading should be ending at value 0 on any given overall time.  The fade start showing the text when ending the text should be gone and not stay. No if I set it to 5 seconds the text in the end stay.

Comment: If you want to stop at 0 only you simply have to remove the check for a value close to 1 (Mathf.Abs(value - 1) <= THRESHOLD) => see edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out Dotween - http://dotween.demigiant.com/
I've used it on  multiple games for the exact question you posed.

CanvasGroup.DOFade(float to, float duration).OnComplete(method);